# Select on aggregate result

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query which does a count from another table then adds a column for the result. I then need to alter the original select results based on that but am being told unknown column.

E.g. the following query does a count from another table within the main query, and the result is named shares, I need to filter the main query result set based on whether that column is greater than 0 but I get error `unknown column shares`

```
select b.name, event_title, ue.event_vis, event_date, 
    (select count(*) from list_shares 
        where user_id = 63 and event_id=ue.user_event_id) as shares,
    (DAYOFYEAR(ue.event_date) - DAYOFYEAR(CURDATE())) as days 
FROM brains b
    join user_events ue on b.user_id=ue.user_id
where b.user_id=63 and ((ue.event_vis='Public') OR (shares>0)) 
    and MOD(DAYOFYEAR(ue.event_date) - DAYOFYEAR(CURDATE()) + 365, 365) <= 30 
order by days asc
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using a derived table to deliver the aggregate value and join it as you would do with a "phyiscal" table. Example:

```
select
    b.name,
    ue.event_title,
    ue.event_vis,
    ue.event_date, 
    tmp.shares,
    (DAYOFYEAR(ue.event_date) - DAYOFYEAR(CURDATE())) as days

from
    brains b join user_events ue on b.user_id = ue.user_id
    left join (
        select
            ls.user_id,
            ls.event_id,
            count(*) as shares
        from
            list_shares ls
        group by
            ls.user_id,
            ls.event_id) tmp on b.user_id = tmp.user_id and ue.user_event_id = tmp.event_id

where
    b.user_id = 63
and
    ((ue.event_vis = 'Public') OR (tmp.shares > 0))
and 
    MOD(DAYOFYEAR(ue.event_date) - DAYOFYEAR(CURDATE()) + 365, 365) <= 30 

order by
    days asc
```

Please note the "left join". Because your using the OR operator in your where clause it seems to me like you want to get also rows without a share.

Of course you could also use the same subselect in your where clause but that's duplicate code and harder to maintain.

Comment: That tells me Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'tmp.event_id' in 'on clause'

Comment: Sorry, I missed to add the additional column "event_id" in derived table as I discovered that you used it as a field in your subselect join.

Comment: Outstanding! Thanks so much - saved me doing further checking before printing to page which was the original option

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a computed column to filter in the same query. Try something like

```
SELECT x.*
FROM (
    /*Your Query*/
) as x
WHERE x.shares > 0
```

Or you could do something like

```
select b.name, event_title, ue.event_vis, event_date, 
    shares.SharesCount as shares,
    (DAYOFYEAR(ue.event_date) - DAYOFYEAR(CURDATE())) as days 
FROM brains b
    join user_events ue on b.user_id=ue.user_id, event_id 
    JOIN (select count(*) as [sharesCount],  from list_shares 
        where user_id = 63) as shares ON shares.event_id = ue.user_event_id
where b.user_id=63 and ((ue.event_vis='Public') OR (shares>0)) 
    and MOD(DAYOFYEAR(ue.event_date) - DAYOFYEAR(CURDATE()) + 365, 365) <= 30
    AND shares.sharesCount > 0
order by days asc
```